# How to get the line number in error in java?

Tags: java, error-handling

I know that the line in error is `to_return = find(list,false);` How can I get the line number of this line when there is `NullPointerException` type of error? Or in line number in general?

I tried few things. The closest is this one `Called.getLineNumber()` which gives me the line number of `StackTraceElement Called = new Throwable().fillInStackTrace().getStackTrace()[0];`

```
public TestObject[] myfind(Subitem list )throws Exception{
    TestObject[]to_return=null;
    try {
        to_return = find(list,false);
    }
    catch (RationalTestException ex) {
        //logStoreException(ex);
        StackTraceElement Called = new Throwable().fillInStackTrace().getStackTrace()[0];
        StackTraceElement Calling = new Throwable().fillInStackTrace().getStackTrace()[1];
        throw new Exception (this.add_debugging_info(Called, Calling, ex.getMessage()));

    }   
    catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        StackTraceElement Called = new Throwable().fillInStackTrace().getStackTrace()[0];
        StackTraceElement Calling = new Throwable().fillInStackTrace().getStackTrace()[1];
        logStoreException(npe);
        System.out.println("Line number: "+npe.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()); 
        System.out.println("Line number2: "+Integer.toString(Called.getLineNumber()));
        System.out.println(this.add_debugging_info(Called, Calling, npe.getMessage()));
        throw new Exception (this.add_debugging_info(Called, Calling, npe.getMessage()));
    }   
    catch (Exception ex) {
        StackTraceElement Called = new Throwable().fillInStackTrace().getStackTrace()[0];
        StackTraceElement Calling = new Throwable().fillInStackTrace().getStackTrace()[1];
        throw new Exception (this.add_debugging_info(Called, Calling, ex.getMessage()));

    } 
    finally {
        //unregisterAll();
        //unregister(to);
        return to_return;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you compile with observability on, the line number should be listed in the exception traceback.

Comment: Your code is creating an exception and asking where that exception was created.  To get the line number of a real exception you need to use the real exception, not one you created.

Comment: (Ie, call `getStackTrace` on `ex`.)  (And *don't* call `fillInStackTrace`, as that would overwrite the info in the caught exception.)

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just do `npe.printStackTrace();`/why your runtime code needs to have the line number?  If you just want the line number information to propagate through the `Exception` you are re-throwing, you can always just do `throw new Exception(npe);`, which will keep all of the details about the original `Exception`.

Comment: @aroth: `npe.printStackTrace();` doesn't contain the line number that caused the error on the level where I called myfind() when I do `throw new Exception(npe);` in myfind(). If I do `npe.printStackTrace();` inside myfind the line number is there.

Comment: @HotLicks: It works but the line number is in `npe.getStackTrace()[5].getLineNumber()` how would I know the right index? I guess it won't be always index number 5.

Comment: How big is the array you get from `getStackTrace`?  (Hint: Assign the result of `getStackTrace` to a local variable, so you don't have to keep refetching it.)

Comment: (And printStackTrace would work just fine, if you called it with *the original* exception, rather than the one you created.  You *are* aware that `Exception` is a subclass of `Throwable`, right?)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you just want the current stack trace, use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`
2. If you want to force the JVM to fill in the stack traces, please set the option `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` on your JVM.

Answer (score 0):

When running in Eclipse, to get the line number itself, you need to get the StackTrace array and call getLineNumber() on it.

The following worked for me in my Utils class, isSessionConnectible method:

```
... catch (ClassFormatError cfe) {
        logger.error("Problem ClassFormatError connecting. " + cfe.getMessage() + " " + cfe.getCause());
        int size = cfe.getStackTrace().length - 1;
        logger.error("   Root cause: " + cfe.getStackTrace()[size].getMethodName() + " " + cfe.getStackTrace()[size].getClassName());
        if (size>1) { 
            logger.error("   Penultimate cause: method=" + cfe.getStackTrace()[size-1].getMethodName() + " class=" + cfe.getStackTrace()[size-1].getClassName() + 
                    " line=" + cfe.getStackTrace()[size-1].getLineNumber()); 
        }
```

Result when thrown:

```
2018-07-06 12:00:12 ERROR Utils:319 - Problem ClassFormatError connecting to Hibernate. Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/transaction/SystemException null
2018-07-06 12:00:12 ERROR Utils:322 -    Root cause: main <mypackage>.Utils
2018-07-06 12:00:12 ERROR Utils:324 -    Penultimate cause: method=isSessionConnectible class=<mypackage>.Utils line=306
```

BTW, in Eclipse, make sure that Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Compiler has the checkbox marked at "Add line number attributes to generated class files".